# How to close a PRAW Reddit instance?

Tags: python-3.x, praw

Is there a way to close a PRAW reddit instance?  I'm using multithreading and in order to update the user data I'm initializing a new instance of reddit with the same parameters and then attaching that to `r`, but then am getting errors for too many connections.

```
prawcore.exceptions.RequestException: error with request HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.reddit.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/access_token (Caused by SSLError(OSError(24, 'Too many open files'),))
```

What I'd like to do is be able to close each reddit instance before instantiating a new one to prevent this error.

Thanks for any and all advice.